# Variable scope, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables, scope

I need to perform a GET request as attribute (outside viewDidLoad() ) in order to access some filed in other function.
This is what I tried:

```
var my_id: Int!
var note: [String]? {
    didSet{
        let x = service()
        x.getStuff(id: my_id ) { (response, error) in
            note = response?.results
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner and I don't know how to do this. (I know this is not working)
My_id is here with a performSegue from another view.
Thank you!

Comment: `getStuff` appears to be an asynchronous process, so it takes time before `note` will be set.  The approach you have here isn't suitable for asynchronous requests

Comment: So what's the best approach? What should I do

Comment: You can take a look at the answers in the duplicate, but essentially you need to call `getStuff` and do whatever you need with the data in the closure itself.  Your current code doesn't make much sense anyway, because a `didSet` will fire when `note` is set, not when it is read, and because you set `note` in the closure, you would have an infinite recursive loop